# An elegant way to handle flashdata with AJAX on every page on Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

As the next request to CI erases flashdata. An app that requires an AJAX call on every page will make flashdata useless. I have worked around this by running keep_flashdata() on every single item on the AJAX controller method.

In my particular use case, an AJAX call is made on every page load to pull notifications from the web app.

Is there a more elegant way to handle this? Are there patterns which support this use case(which perhaps CI can adopt)?

Comment: If you want to use temporary data on every page, you can directly use CI sessions instead of flash data

Comment: Clarification: I don't need it on every page. I only need it at the next request. However, after building a notifications widget which calls CI every time the page loads, flashdata is immediately cleared. The AJAX call is made at $(document).ready(); and clears the flashdata I saved.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use it in every pages then you can put it in CI sessions instead of CI flash data.

Use this to set and unset sessions variables respectively whenever you needed.

```
$this->session->set_userdata('some_name', 'some_value');
$this->session->unset_userdata('some_name');
```

CodeIgniter supports "flashdata", or session data that will only be available for the **next server request**, and are then automatically cleared. These can be very useful, and are typically used for informational or status messages.

You can  preserve a flashdata variable through an additional request using    keep_flashdata(). But it is not an elegant way to use keep_flashdata() to avail data on every pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `My_Controller` to be extended by all your controllers and keep `flashdata` after checking if it is an `AJAX` request.

```
    class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
    {
        function __construct ()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            #code shared with all controllers
            if( isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && 
                !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && 
                strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest'
            )
            {    
                $this->session->keep_flashdata('your_data');   
            }
        }
    }
```

Of course this is not an elegant solution, because you can never know for sure if the request was made via `AJAX`.

Comment: Actually there's a $this->input->is_ajax_request() - https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html

Comment: great :) didn't knew about that